# Is there a way to compound functions in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, statistics, operator-overloading

**General question :**

If there are two objects `A` and `B` with respective functions `f_A(arg list)` and `f_B(arg list)`.

What's the best way to create an object C with a function compounded of f_A(...) and f_B(...) ?
for example :  `f_C() = f_A() + f_B()  or f_C() = f_A(f_B())`

Is it possible to overload the "+" operator such that we can create the object C doing something like that ?

```
auto object_c = object_a + object_b
```

**Here is a sample of my code :**

```
class GaussianKernel : public Kernel {
        public:
            GaussianKernel(double sigma) : m_sigma(sigma), m_scale(1) {}

            double covarianceFunction(
                double   X,
                double   Y
            )
            {
                double result;

                result = m_scale  *  exp(-norm(X - Y) / (m_sigma*m_sigma));

                return result;      
            }


            GaussianKernel operator+(const GaussianKernel& b) {
            /*Here I would like to overload the + operator such that 
            I can create a kernel from two others kernels, 
            I mean with a covariance function compound of the previous ones 
            */
            }
        private:
            double m_sigma;
            double m_scale;
        };
```

Thanks you.

Comment: in general `f_A() + f_B()` is something completely different than `f_A( f_B() )` which one do you want?

Comment: That's true, I would like `f_A() + f_B()` first.

Comment: in that case you just need an `operator+` for whatever is the return type of these methods, what do they return? In your example it is `double` with means you dont have to do anything extra

Comment: Is `covarianceFunction` a virtual function inherited from `Kernel`?

Comment: In your example code you are trying to overload `operator +` that would somehow combine two other objects into third object. How is "covariance function compound of the previous ones" related to this? You don't even have functions to combine.

Comment: @VTT I don't see the problem, why the third kernel can't be composition of two others kernels ?

Comment: @sebrockm Yes and even pure virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with prototype solution like this:

```
class FooKernel : public Kernel {
public:
    FooKernel (std::function<double(double, double)> fun) : fun_(fun) {}
    double covarianceFunction(
            double   X,
            double   Y
        ) const {
        return fun_(X, Y);
    }

   template<class T>
   auto operator+(const T &b) const {
       return FooKernel([b, this](double X, double Y){
           return this->covarianceFunction(X, Y) + b.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
       });
   }
private:
    std::function<double(double, double)> fun_;
};    


class GaussianKernel : public Kernel {
    public:
        GaussianKernel(double sigma) : m_sigma(sigma), m_scale(1) {}

        double covarianceFunction(
            double   X,
            double   Y
        ) const 
        {
            double result;
            result = m_scale  *  exp(-norm(X - Y) / (m_sigma*m_sigma));
            return result;      
        }

   template<class T>
   auto operator+(const T &b) const {
       return FooKernel([b, this](double X, double Y){
           return this->covarianceFunction(X, Y) + b.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
       });
   }
    private:
        double m_sigma;
        double m_scale;
};
```

No longer lambdas are used, but now uses Your function as You wished.

Later on I would try to remove the `std::function` as it may have quite big performance impact. Instead I would make the `FooKernel` a class template, that stores callable by value.

Comment: your approach is not composable in the sense that your `operator+` returns a lambda on which you cannot call `operator+` another time. What if you want to combine 3 or more kernels? `auto D = A + B + C;` wont work this way

Comment: uh sorry maybe I am wrong and it does (B+C returns lambda  and `A + (B+C)` should be fine)

Comment: Wrapping this into `std::function` also has pretty severe performance implications. I would absolutely _not_ want such a simple kernel calculation to be subject to that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I also would not do it this way in my code, but for sake of simplicity and less LOC it did it without template magic

Answer (score 3):

Given two methods `f_A` and `f_B` you can get `f_C` returning the sum of the others by using for example a lambda:

```
auto f_C = [](/*param*/){ return f_A(/*param*/) + f_B(/*param*/); };
auto sum_result = f_C(param);
```

To get the compound method it would be this:

```
auto f_C = [](/*param*/){ return f_B( f_A(/*param*/)); };
auto compound_result = f_C(param);
```

PS: I know that this is not directly applicable to your example, still trying to find out what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry if I am not clear. I would like to implement kernels (in my case object which can compute the covariance between two random variable) and in a mathematical way, kernels can be combined with others kernels with some rules (addition, scaling, etc.) . So I have create a simple covariance method which return a double and I would like to create easily kernels with more complicated functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another subclass of `Kernel`:

```
class CompoundGaussianKernel : public Kernel {
    public:
        CompoundGaussianKernel(GaussianKernel const& kernel1, GaussianKernel const& kernel2) 
            : m_kernel1(kernel1), m_kernel2(kernel2) 
        {}

        double covarianceFunction(double X, double Y)
        {
            return m_kernel1.covarianceFunction(X, Y) + m_kernel2.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
            // or any other composition than "+"
        }

    private:
        GaussianKernel m_kernel1;
        GaussianKernel m_kernel2;
    };
```

I recommend not to define `operator+` inside of a class but as a free function.

```
CompoundGaussianKernel operator+(GaussianKernel const& kernel1, GaussianKernel const& kernel2)
{
    return CompoundGaussianKernel(kernel1, kernel2);
}
```

Comment: Hiding the inherited `covarianceFunction` is not good practice though. It should probably be virtual.

Comment: OP has not answered my question wether it is virtual in `Kernel` or not. Anyway, if it is then it will implicitly stay virtual. It will be overridden by any subclass. If it is not virtual on the other hand, it will be hidden by a subclass, no matter if the subclass declares it virtual or not

Comment: Oh my bad, you inherit from `Kernel` not `GaussianKernel`. In that case it is of course as correct as OP's version.